# Insert row in gridview in DevExpress

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I'm trying to add value to my gridview, but never inserted, but neither are inserted, even remove the "if ( gvProcess.IsNewItemRow (rowHandle)) " for equal work , but neither are inserted.

```
private void add_new_row(string val1,string val2,string val3,string val4,string val5)
{
    //gvProcess.OptionsBehavior.Editable = true;

    gvProcess.AddNewRow();

    int rowHandle = gvProcess.GetRowHandle(gvProcess.DataRowCount);
    if (gvProcess.IsNewItemRow(rowHandle))
    {
        gvProcess.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gvProcess.Columns[0], val1);
        gvProcess.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gvProcess.Columns[1], val2);
        gvProcess.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gvProcess.Columns[2], val3);
        gvProcess.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gvProcess.Columns[3], val4);
        gvProcess.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gvProcess.Columns[4], val5);

    }

    gvProcess.UpdateCurrentRow();

    MessageBox.Show("Done");

}
```

what is the problem?

Comment: If any of Answer helped you, so you would mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Instead of, you can use this >

```
DataTable dtMain = ((DataTable)gcGrid.DataSource);
DataRow newRow = dtMain.NewRow();
newRow["Column1"] = "";
dtMain.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

resp

```
        private void add_new_row(string val1, string val2, string val3, string val4, string val5)
        {
          //gcProcess
          if (gcProcess.DataSource != null)
          {
            gcProcess.BeginUpdate();
            DataTable dtMain = ((DataTable)gcProcess.DataSource);
            DataRow newRow = dtMain.NewRow();
            newRow[0] = val1;
            newRow[1] = val2;
            newRow[2] = val3;
            newRow[3] = val4;
            newRow[4] = val5;
            dtMain.Rows.Add(newRow);
            gcProcess.EndUpdate();
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ColumnView.AddNewRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_AddNewRowtopic) method is only supported for data sources implementing the `System.ComponentModel.IBindingList` interface. In other cases, you should use the methods provided by your data source to add new rows.

Take a look at the [Adding and Deleting Records](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument752) help-article for details.